# async fetch not called when page loaded

Tags: javascript, axios, nuxtjs

On my page I have a async fetch() method which is used to get some data from an api, to display it on the page. The code looks like this:

```
data(){
    return{
        name : "",

    }

},

async fetch()
{
    console.log(this.$route.params.slug)
    const d2 = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/Movie/'+this.$route.params.slug)
    const d1 = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/Episodes/'+this.$route.params.slug+'/0')
    console.log(d2.data);
    console.log(d1.data)

    this.name = d2.data.name

}
```

When I am trying to load the page using a nuxt link on a different page or if i return to the page, the fetch method is not called. I have to reload the page every time using f5 to see the data again.

Comment: How is your `fetch()` function called?

Comment: it is called called on the server by nuxtjs:  https://nuxtjs.org/blog/understanding-how-fetch-works-in-nuxt-2-12/

Comment: I guess you used UNIVERSAL mode, so change the project mode to SPA after that you can debug your code and the network